# How to get the pivot lines from two tab-separated files?

Tags: python, shell, csv, dictionary, hashmap

Given two files `file1.txt`

```
abc def \t 123 456
jkl mno \t 987 654
foo bar \t 789 123
bar bar \t 432
```

and `file2.txt`

```
foo bar \t hello world
abc def \t good morning
xyz \t 456
```

The task is to extract the lines where the first column matches and achieve:

```
abc def \t 123 456 \t good morning
foo bar \t 789 123 \t hello world
```

I can do it in Python as such:

```
from io import StringIO

file1 = """abc def \t 123 456
jkl mno \t 987 654
foo bar \t 789 123
bar bar \t 432"""


file2 = """foo bar \t hello world
abc def \t good morning
xyz \t 456"""

map1, map2 = {}, {}

with StringIO(file1) as fin1:
    for line in file1.split('\n'):
        one, two = line.strip().split('\t')
        map1[one] = two
    
    
with StringIO(file2) as fin2:
    for line in file2.split('\n'):
        one, two = line.strip().split('\t')
        map2[one] = two
        
        
for k in set(map1).intersection(set(map2)):
    print('\t'.join([k, map1[k], map2[k]]))
```

The actual task files have billions of lines, **are there faster solution without loading everything and keeping the hashmaps/dictionaries?**

Maybe using unix/bash commands? Would pre-sorting the files help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `join` command is sometimes hard to work with, but here it's straightforward:

```sh
join -t $'\t' <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

That uses bash's [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to specify the tab separator, and [process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to treat program output as a file.

To see the output, pipe the above into `cat -A` to see the tabs represented as `^I`:

```
abc def^I123 456^Igood morning$
foo bar^I789 123^Ihello world$
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{key = $1 FS $2} FNR==NR {sub(/^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2}/, ""); map[key] = $0; next} key in map {print $0, map[key]}' file2.txt file1.txt

abc def \t 123 456 \t good morning
foo bar \t 789 123 \t hello world
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '{
   key = $1 FS $2
}
FNR == NR {
   sub(/^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2}/, "")
   map[key] = $0
   next
}
key in map {
   print $0, map[key]
}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

It only loads data from `file2` into memory and processes records of `file1` line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and its join verb

```
mlr --tsv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output join -j 1 --rp 2 -f file1.txt file2.txt >output.tsv
```

The output will be (it's only a preview, you will have tab separator):

```
| foo bar | 789 123 | hello world  |
| abc def | 123 456 | good morning |
```